# Laravel Why my drop down menu is showing all elements when hovered?

Tags: php, html, laravel

In my navbar I am showing the parent items. Which I am getting by using `getItems()` method. It is being linked to every item. And every parent item has some child items. Which I am getting using `($item->children as $child)` And when one hovers over any parent item, the child items of that parent item should be visible from drop down.

The problem is whenever I hover around any item, every child item is being shown in the drop down. But I want only the child item of the parent item to be shown. The problem is likely with my `@foreach` loops. But I am not getting where. It would be nice If someone can help me out. Thanks in advance.

This is my blade file code.

```
<div class="navbar-list">
      <div class="dropdown">
        @foreach(getItems() as $item)
          <a href="{{ route('item.shop.list') }}?item={{ $item->id }}">{{ $item->name }}</a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu">
            @foreach ($item->children as $child)
              <li class="dropdown-item" data-id="{{ $child->id }}" data-name="{{ $child->name }}">
                <span>{{ $child->name }}</span>
              </li>
            @endforeach
          </div>
        @endforeach       
      </div> 
    </div>
```

And here is it's style

```
<style>
 .dropdown:hover>.dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
  
}
.dropdown>.dropdown-toggle:active {
    pointer-events: none;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Have you tried adding `<div class="dropdown">` (and its closing div) _inside_ your `@foreach`?

Comment: Let me try and I'll let you know.

Comment: Works fine. Thank you. It is kind of irritating that I couldn't find it myself. And I spent 2+ hours trying to figure it out.

Comment: What to do with the question? No answers but my problem is solved. It needs to be closed. @kerbh0lz post it as answer and I will accept it. And this will close the question. And again thanks a bunch man.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every item in your first `@foreach` needs to be its own dropdown. Place `<div class="dropdown">` *inside* your loop:

```
<div class="navbar-list">
  @foreach(getItems() as $item)
    <div class="dropdown">
      <a href="{{ route('item.shop.list') }}?item={{ $item->id }}">{{ $item->name }}</a>
      <div class="dropdown-menu">
        @foreach ($item->children as $child)
          <li class="dropdown-item" data-id="{{ $child->id }}" data-name="{{ $child->name }}">
            <span>{{ $child->name }}</span>
          </li>
        @endforeach
      </div>
    </div> 
  @endforeach       
</div>
```